# Closing sessions in unexpected situations

Tags: c#, php, session

I build a session mechanism in PHP. when the app has been closed it send close session request to the server.
My question is how I can mark session as closed if the application crash or the internet connection has been failed.How the server can know it?
I think about a job that ping the server from each application but it looks too heavy even if it happened once a moment.
My application is in c#.
Thank u.

Comment: This is one of the annoyances of the fact that http is stateless. There is no real solution to this. The typical approach is to rely on a session timeout and have some sort of cleanup routine that removes outdated sessions in an asynchronous way. If you need to know _right away_ that the session should be terminated then you should rethink if http really is the best protocol choice. You also might want to take a look at "long polling".

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how I can mark session as closed if the application crash or the internet connection has been failed. How the server can know it?

The server does not know about the crash and it can not know about it as well. It still waits for the close-request to come.

So the only thing the server can do is, when it waits too long for the close-request to assume that the session is closed.

To make this more easy, not only send a close-request to the server, but also send an alive-request to the server each minute.

If there is not alive request for lets say three minutes, then the server knows that something went wrong.